# Emails sending with postfix fail to outlook emails but success with gmail

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

I have set up postfix server. I am testing my email sending . i can send to gmail but all outlook mails are getting rejected, may i know how can i fix ? Any config i have to change ?

```
Nov 27 10:35:15 mail-mymail.com postfix/10025/smtpd[1171]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 27 10:35:15 mail-mymail.com postfix/qmgr[1119]: 4Cj9xb6tj8zB4HHl: from=<contact@mymail.net>, size=2026, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 27 10:35:15 mail-mymail.com amavis[27451]: (27451-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, ORIGINATING/MYNETS LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:56474 ESMTP/ESMTP <contact@mymail.net
> -> <testmail.001@outlook.com>, (), Queue-ID: 4Cj9xb1YyrzB4HJ8, Message-ID: <6d0510c8a2ad1ca2fe297c292ed6d43e@mymail.net>, mail_id: LnXcD8krJnq8, b: pmqLzJBID, Hits: -0
.999, size: 776, queued_as: 4Cj9xb6tj8zB4HHl, Subject: "Heyyyy", From: <contact@mymail.net>, User-Agent: Roundcube_Webmail, helo=localhost, Tests: [ALL_TRUSTED=-1,TVD
_SPACE_RATIO=0.001], autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no, autolearnscore=0.001, dkim_new=dkim:mymail.net, 691 ms
Nov 27 10:35:15 mail-mymail.com amavis[27451]: (27451-01) Passed CLEAN, <contact@mymail.net> -> <testmail.001@outlook.com>, Hits: -0.999, tag=2, tag2=6.2, kill=6.9, qu
eued_as: 4Cj9xb6tj8zB4HHl, L/0/0/0
Nov 27 10:35:15 mail-mymail.com postfix/amavis/smtp[1165]: 4Cj9xb1YyrzB4HJ8: to=<testmail.001@outlook.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.82, delays=0.1/0.02
/0.01/0.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4Cj9xb6tj8zB4HHl)
Nov 27 10:35:15 mail-mymail.com postfix/qmgr[1119]: 4Cj9xb1YyrzB4HJ8: removed
Nov 27 10:35:16 mail-mymail.com postfix/smtp[1172]: 4Cj9xb6tj8zB4HHl: to=<testmail.001@outlook.com>, relay=outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx]:25, delay=0.56, delays=0.01/0.02/0.4/0.13, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx] said: 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3150). You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. [XXX.XXXX.prod.protection.outlook.com] (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Nov 27 10:35:16 mail-mymail.com postfix/smtp[1172]: 4Cj9xb6tj8zB4HHl: lost connection with outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx] while sending RCPT TO
Nov 27 10:35:16 mail-mymail.com postfix/cleanup[1160]: 4Cj9xc3s5gzB4HJK: message-id=<4Cj9xc3s5gzB4HJK@mail.mymail.net>





Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [XXX.XXX.XX.XX]
    weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of
    their network is on our block list (S3150). You can also refer your
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the log: the sending IP is in a range that is blocked by Microsoft.  If you control the range, you could ask to have it unblocked, but if you only have that one IP, then you are out of luck.  Send from a different IP address.